# What causes VIsual Studio to not find the dll?

Tags: c#, dll

Morning Ya'all,

I recently got in touch with dlls. At the moment the only way of using Classes from the dll (added as a reference) is by copying the dlls in the bin\debug folder. When I try to start the .EXE with the dlls in a seperate folder, it gives an error that VS could not find the dependency...

I heard about configuration data files and AssemblyResolve, but so far could not find pieces of code that fixed my issue nor I understood. I am programming in C# btw.

Thx for everyone sharing his thoughts on this topic.

Comment: check this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/87581da3-d8d4-43cb-85dc-dd7f2c8f60d6/visual-studio-2017-ssrs-report-reference-external-barcodedll-can-not-be-l?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Dlls that you added to dependencies should be copied to bin/Debug when you build the project. There must be something wrong with your project or the way you added the dependencies.

Comment: If you have project for that DLL, add references by project to currently working project, DLL file will be automatically copy to the Debug/Release folder

Answer (score -1):

Create a `libs` folder in your project, copy the dll's into the folder and reference them in the project from the `libs` folder. When you build, it will include the dll's along side your exe.

Comment: okay, thank you for the answer. But in this case I would have to copy my dlls in a specific folder. Why is it not enough that I give VS the path to the dll?